# session in httphandler

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

I am using session in 2 http handler and also  added IRequiresSessionState , IReadOnlySessionState

```
Imports System.Web.SessionState
Public Class Handler : Implements IHttpHandler , IRequiresSessionState , IReadOnlySessionState
```

In http handler 1 create session

```
context.Session("id") = "1"
```

and in http handler 2 access to session

```
Dim i As String = CStr(context.Session("id"))
```

The problem here is that http handler 2 session("id") =  nothing

why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `IReadOnlySessionState`